# Select input appened to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that is appended to a div tag through a location.href reload.  How would select that input field using jQuery?  If I add it to the page it won't work, I'm assuming because the input isn't loaded into the DOM yet.

```
$('#fileName1').focus(function() {
  alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
});
```

Comment: This is not very clear about appending div tag through a location.hfref, can you explain more. thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#fileName1').live('focus', function() {
  alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
});
```